# Android OpenGL ES rotate a cube on x, y, z points, and the cube's center

Tags: android, opengl-es

I want to: rotate my cube on a x,y,z center point. And the second way: i want to rotate my cube on my cube's center points. How i can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a OpenGL ES GL10 object called gl, in your ondraw or similar:

```
  // Push matrix so we can pop later
  gl.glPushMatrix();

  // Translate to the center of your cube
  // Or to whatever xyz point you want
  glTranslatef(centreX, centreY, 0);

  // rotation = degrees to rotate
  // x,y,z are unit vectors for rotation to take place
  // I.E  x=0.0 y=0.0 z=0.0 would rotate around the z-axis
  gl.glRotatef(rotation, x, y, z);


  // CUBE DRAWING FUNCTION HERE


  // Popmatrix so we undo translation and rotation for
  // rest of opengl calls
  gl.glPopMatrix();
```

I suggest looking at [the android ports of the nehe opengl tutorials](http://insanitydesign.com/wp/projects/nehe-android-ports/) as they are brilliant guides to starting opengl with android.

Comment: on the Z axis, its work, its rotate on the cube's center, but on the x,y axis it doesnt work.. in that way the center points not in the cubes center, but anywhere else is the center...

Comment: Please add a snippet of your code above so I can see what the problem is.